# Insert query in R shiny app returns: Column count does not match value count

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I am building a shiny app that needs to take user input and insert into the database.I have a user table in MySQL with `columns(id(Auto increment),username,password)`. I am trying to insert values into that table but it keeps crashing while returning an error on possible mismatch of columns and values. However, I have checked and this not the case. Below is my insert code.

```
query<-paste(c("INSERT INTO user(username,password) 
VALUES('",paste(username),",",paste(password),"')"),collapse = "")
```

this query is then passed as an argument to

```
dbGetQuery(db, query)
```

Comment: Hard to anwer this way. Are you sure `username` and `password` are the correct way to catch user input? Not `input$username`?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include. All this is in a function whose parameters take username and password when it's called. So, they can be accessed. The function is triggered by a button click for submit

Comment: I have also tried this query now but it only submits the  username.                                                   
                                                                                                       
    query <- sprintf(  "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ('%s')",
    table,
    c("username","password"),
    c(paste(username),paste(password)))

Comment: try this: VALUES('",paste(username),"','",paste(password),"')"),collapse = "") // two ' were miss.. Try to print the query before execute..

Comment: This worked. Thanks